# How to do .forEach() for object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a data structure similar to:

```
var object = {
  name: "a",
  number: "1",
  mission: ['a','b','c']
}
```

Now I want to update them into the database so I need to walk them.

I tried:

```
object.forEach(function(value, key, map){
  console.log('value: ' + value + ', key: ' + key + ', map:' + map);
});
```

And then the console report an error: `object.forEach is not a function`

Comment: `forEach` should be invoked on arrays not with an object. If you try on array of objects , it will work

Comment: `for(var key in object) console.log(key, object);`

Comment: In modern JS `Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(\`key: ${key}, value: ${value}\`));`

With polyfills and transpilers this should run anywhere :p

Comment: ugh - that duplicate needs modernization!!!

Comment: This is not a very good duplicate, because (1) no answers mention `Object.entries` and (2) it is mainly about chunking.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "flat array in the object and do not output map". `object[key]`, where key is the index of a `for...in` loop, or a `forEach` on `Object.keys`, will return the array as-is.

Comment: @torazaburo later i realized it was just the console itself has flatten the array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(key=>{
    console.log(key ,object[key]);
})
```

Comment: thanks, how do i output map? also this seems to flat array into string...

Comment: @AeroWang well in`forEach` third argument is actual array itself on which you have called `forEach`. Array is converting into string because we are adding it with a string.

Comment: how to keep it as an array?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.

```
var object = {
  name: "a",
  number: "1",
  mission: ['a','b','c']
}
for(var key in object) console.log(key, object[key]);
```

Comment: thanks, how do i output map? also this seems to flat array into string...

Answer (score -1):

Use this,

```
 for (var item in object) {
    console.log('value: ' + object['name'] + ', key: ' + object['number'] + ', map:' + object['mission']);
 }
```

Comment: no, the key in the object will change, they might not be name, number, and mission

Comment: Why are you looping over the keys with `item`, but then not doing anything with it?